# Can EE multiple relationship fields be displayed nested?

Tags: relationships

Can EE multiple relationship fields be displayed nested? I'm not able to get this working, and it's not clear from [the Relationships docs page](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/relationships.html) if it's supposed to.

Say I have 3 channels -- bands, albums and songs -- and my relationship fields are top-down rather than bottom-up, ie, bands have a multiple relationship field of albums, and albums have a multiple relationship field of songs. I want to display a list of bands, and within each band its albums, and within each album its songs. In the following example, songs do not appear:

```
<ul>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="bands"}
    <li> 
        {title}
        <ul>
            {bands_albums}
            <li>
                {bands_albums:title}
                <ul>
                    {bands_albums:albums_songs}
                    <li>
                        {bands_albums:albums_songs:title}
                    <li>
                    {/bands_albums:albums_songs}
                </ul>
            </li>
            {/bands_albums}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

I can get a single song from each album to appear by removing the inner loop:

```
<ul>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="bands"}
    <li> 
        {title}
        <ul>
            {bands_albums}
            <li>
                {bands_albums:title}
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        {bands_albums:albums_songs:title}
                    <li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            {/bands_albums}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

But I need all the songs.

Comment: On the innermost tag, have you tried it as {albums_songs:title} instead of {bands_albums:albums_songs:title} ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried it and it doesn't do anything. Has it worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I think I've done this successfully before... Maybe try using the `parents` or `children` tag in conjunction with a `channel` parameter like this:

```
<ul>
  {exp:channel:entries channel="bands"}
   <li> 
    {title}
    <ul>
        {bands_albums}
        <li>
            {bands_albums:title}
            <ul>
                {bands_albums:parents channel="songs"}
                  <li>
                     {bands_albums:parents:title}  
                  <li>
                {/bands_albums:parents}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {/bands_albums}
    </ul>
   </li>
  {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they should be nestable. I have the following code working - all the relationships are within one channel. I built it as a way to see if relationships could be used intra-channel to build navigation:

```
<h2>The Family Tree from the Top Down </h2>
{exp:channel:entries channel="people" disable="member_data|pagination|categories"}

  {if count==1} {!-- start the top-level unordered list --}
    <ul>
  {/if}

    {parents field="offspring"}
        {if parents:no_results} {!-- entries with no parents are top-level --}
            <li>
              {title}
              {offspring} {!-- second level entries --}

                {if offspring:count == 1}<ul>{/if} {!-- open the second-level unordered list --}

                    <li>
                      {offspring:title}
                      {offspring:offspring} {!-- third level entries --}

                        {if offspring:offspring:count == 1}
                          <ul> {!-- open 3rd level list --}
                        {/if}

                        <li>{offspring:offspring:title}</li>

                        {if offspring:offspring:count==offspring:offspring:total_results}
                          </ul> {!-- close third-level list --}
                        {/if}

                      {/offspring:offspring}
                    </li>

                {if offspring:count==offspring:total_results}
                  </ul> {!-- close second-level list --}
                {/if}

              {/offspring}
            </li>
        {/if}
    {/parents}

    {if count==total_results}
      </ul> {!-- close top-level list --}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```